WidgetKit Mac OS only refreshing one widget
I have a Mac OS application providing widgets with Intent using WidgetKit.
There is no timeline and the widgets need to be refreshed using:
WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()
My issue is that it refreshes only one widget out of X.
If I delete the widget that refreshes, it starts to refresh another one, but it only refresh one widget when the reloadAllTimelines() is called.
If I check the number of widgets with WidgetCenter.shared.getCurrentConfigurations(), I get the correct amount of configured widgets.
I would expect it to reload all the widgets.
Am I missing something?
My widget configuration looks like this:
var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        AppIntentConfiguration(kind: kind, intent: PersonWidgetIntent.self, provider: Provider()) {
            EntryView(entry: $0)
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("Person Widget")
        .description("Pick a person to display.")
        .supportedFamilies([.systemSmall])
    }

and my provider like this:
struct Provider: AppIntentTimelineProvider {
        func getEntry(configuration: PersonWidgetIntent) -> Entry {
            var person = PersonEntity.demo
            var value: WidgetValueData? = nil
            if let personEntity = configuration.person {
                person = personEntity
                value = WidgetDataProvider.shared.getValue(id: person.id)
            }

            return Entry(person: person, value: value)
        }

        func placeholder(in context: Context) -> Entry {
            .placeholder
        }

        func snapshot(
            for configuration: PersonWidgetIntent,
            in context: Context
        ) async -> Entry {
            print("Widget.snapshot")
            return getEntry(configuration: configuration)
        }

        func timeline(
            for configuration: PersonWidgetIntent,
            in context: Context
        ) async -> Timeline<Entry> {
            print("Widget.timeline")
            return .init(entries: [getEntry(configuration: configuration)], policy: .never)
        }
}

Also, is there anyway to get the print debug generated from the widget in Xcode to ease the debug?
